# find last day in month and using value change listener in an android app

Tags: java, android, calendar, actionlistener, onchange

I am trying to build an app that uses dates. The user picks the date from a number picker. 
I wrote some code that should update the maximum number of days in the picker so that the user won't be able to choose a day that cant be found in some month (for example pick 31 in feb).
I don't know why but my code doesn't work .

When I Pick February the maximum day is still 31. When I change the month again lets say I pick again January, the max day is now 28. The code works but with delay

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_week);
    final NumberPicker month= (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.month);
    final NumberPicker day = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.day);
    final Button but= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    final TextView text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    final TextView text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
    day.setMaxValue(31);
    day.setMinValue(1);
    month.setMinValue(1);
    month.setMaxValue(12);
    month.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,month.getValue());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
            int d = 0;
            while(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)==month.getValue()){

                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
                d=d+1;


            }


            if (day.getValue()>d){
                day.setValue(d);
            }
            day.setMaxValue(d);
        }
    } );
```

Comment: What exactly does not work ? What happends ?

Comment: I will answer with example: Whet I Pick February the maximum day is still 31. When I change the month again lets say I pick again January, the max day is now 28. The code works but with delay

Comment: My bet is that the value you get from `month` is the one before the change. Try to use the parameter `newVal` instead of `month.getValue()`

Comment: just a suggestion, i haven't found java calender api much helpful and easy, you may have a look at date4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing actually works. But i think you forgot one key factor days and month are 0 based indexing checkout : [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

Try adjusting these to :

```
day.setMaxValue(30);
day.setMinValue(0);
month.setMinValue(0);
month.setMaxValue(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you call `month.getValue()` that will be changed after onValueChenge()

Replace

```
while(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)==month.getValue()){
```

By

```
while(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)==newVal-1){
```

And also

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,newVal-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet to get maximum number of days in a month :

```
int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```